# How to remove left and right panels in category from Magento?

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento. How I can remove or edit these panels. This shows if I click on category.
Screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkhSQ.jpg
How to remove it from administration? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to admin

2) catalog->manage categories

3) select category which you want to be one colomn layout in my example cell phone

4) click on custom design

5) 
Use Parent Category Settings = no

6) Custom Layout Update

```
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. And how please only change the content of the left sidebar? Thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate @ David Lences

Answer (score 3):

try below code

for category listing

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
```

or try for all site

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <default>
            <remove name="right"/>
            <remove name="left"/>
            <reference name="root">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
            </reference>
    </default>
```

add above code in any **handle** in \app\design\frontend\YOUR PACKAGE\YOUR THEME NAME\layout\local.xml

hope this help

Comment: local.xml not exists. only `tag.xml`, `page.xml`, `newsletter.xml`, `checkout.xml` and `catalog.xml`

Comment: create local.xml in layout directory

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest way to do it is get 1column.phtml layout.

And will remove all the CallOuts.